# Echo HTML output in loop not behaving

Tags: php, html

Having an issue with some formatting - got the PHP working, just the HTML that's driving me a little crazy!

I basically am pulling some stuff via an API and want to present it in a grid.  There are multiple listings.

When I format what I think should work, each item gets stacked underneath the preceeding one and doesn't format right.

I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I've been staring at this for days and I can't work out what's wrong - so over to you!

Here's the HTML code that's coming out wrong:

```
<article id="'.$name.'" class="'.$name.' project type-project status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry pj-categs-adult-cats pj-categs-cats pj-categs-male isotope-item shortcode_animated" data-category="adult-cats cats male" style="width: 400px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">

<div class="project_outer">
    <figure class="cmsms_img_rollover_wrap preloader">
        <img width="580" height="460" src="'.$medium_photo.'" class="full-width wp-post-image" alt="'.$name.'" title="'.$name.'">
<div class="cmsms_img_rollover">
    <span class="cmsms_img_rollover_divider"></span>
        <a href="'.$medium_photo.'" rel="ilightbox" title="'.$name.'" class="cmsms_image_link"><span class="cmsms_theme_icon_search"></span></a><a href="http://test.xxxx.org.au/Project/'.$name.'/" title="'.$name.'" class="cmsms_open_link"><span class="cmsms_theme_icon_rollover_open_link"></span></a>
</div>
</figure>
<div class="project_inner">
    <header class="cmsms_project_header entry-header">
    <h6 class="cmsms_project_title entry-title"><a href="http://test.haart.org.au/davetest/?id='.$animal_id.'">'.$name.'</a></h6>
    </header>
<footer class="cmsms_project_footer entry-meta">
    </a>
    </footer>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
</div>
</article>
```

Basically, I want each to display in its own and then when there's no more listings, to close the HTML.

Hit me up if you have no idea what I'm talking about!!!

*EDIT* Full code - slightly redacted below:

```
<?php 

// Start PHP/API Code
//----------------------------------------
// Open CuRL/JSON Stuff

$ch = curl_init();
$pr_id=$_GET['pr_id'];
$url="https://www.xxxxxx.com.au/api/listings?token=1234&group_id=1234&species=Dog&page=$pg";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'X-some-API-Key: 1234',
));
$json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

// Functions relating to the Echo Code
$prpage=($json['page']);
$prperpage=($json['per_page']);
$prtotalpage=($json['total_pages']);
echo '<div class="portfolio grid large_gap perfect cmsms_3 isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 1356px;">
    <h6>Page '.$pg.' of '.$prtotalpage.'</h6>';
foreach($json['listings'] as $listing)
{
    $short_personality=substr($listing['personality'],0,500);
    $peturl="http://www.xxxx.org.au/pet-info/?petid=".$listing['id'];
    $photos=$listing['photos'];
    $medium_photo=$listing['photos'][0]['xlarge_900'];
    $gallery_first=$listing['photos'][0]['large_340'];
    $gender_class=strtolower($listing['gender']);
    $breed_class=strtolower($listing['species']);
    $name=($listing['name']);
    $date=$listing['created_at'];
    $date_updated=$listing['last_updated'];
    $unique_gallery_name="ilightbox['.$inc.']";
    $inc++;
    foreach($listing['photos'] as $photosthumb)
    {
        $photo_thumb_large=$photosthumb["medium_130"];
        $photo_thumb_hidden=$photosthumb["small_80"];
    }

    // General IF/AND/ELSE Statements to refine the Echo Output
    if($listing['photos'] == null) {
        $medium_photo="http://www.xxxx.org.au/wp-content/themes/xxxx/images/photo_coming_soon.png";
    }
    if($listing['desexed'] == "true") {
        $desexed="Yes";
    }
    else {
        $desexed="No";
    }
    if($listing['foster_needed'] == "true") {
        $foster_needed="Yes";
    }
    else {
        $foster_needed="No";
    }
    if($listing['vaccinated'] == "Yes") {
        $vaccinated="yes";
    }
    else {
        $vaccinated="no";
    }
    if($listing['wormed'] == "Yes") {
        $wormed="yes";
    }
    elseif($listing['wormed'] == "No") {
        $wormed="no";
    }
    else {
        $wormed="no";
    }
    if($listing['heart_worm_treated'] == "true") {
        $heart_worm_tested="Yes";
    }
    elseif($listing['heart_worm_treated'] == "Unsure") {
        $heart_worm_tested="Unsure";
    }
    else {
        $heart_worm_tested="No";
    }
    if($listing['species'] == "Dog") {
        $adoption_enquiry_link="http://www.xxxx.org.au/pre-adoption-form-dogs/?dog_name=$name";
        $hwt="list-$heart_worm_tested";
    }
    elseif($listing['species'] == "Cat") {
        $adoption_enquiry_link="http://www.xxxx.org.au/pre-adoption-form-cats/?cat_name=$name";
        $hwt="list-hwt-hidden";
    }

    $animal_id=($listing['id']);

    $adoption_poster_link="http://www.xxxx.org.au/poster.php?animal_id=$animal_id";

    // Echo the output
    echo '<article id="'.$name.'" class="'.$name.' project type-project status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry pj-categs-adult-cats pj-categs-cats pj-categs-male isotope-item shortcode_animated" data-category="adult-cats cats male" style="width: 400px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
           <div class="project_outer">
               <figure class="cmsms_img_rollover_wrap preloader">
                   <img width="580" height="460" src="'.$medium_photo.'" class="full-width wp-post-image" alt="'.$name.'" title="'.$name.'">
                   <div class="cmsms_img_rollover">
                       <span class="cmsms_img_rollover_divider"></span>
                       <a href="'.$medium_photo.'" rel="ilightbox" title="'.$name.'" class="cmsms_image_link"><span class="cmsms_theme_icon_search"></span></a><a href="http://test.xxxx.org.au/Project/'.$name.'/" title="'.$name.'" class="cmsms_open_link"><span class="cmsms_theme_icon_rollover_open_link"></span></a>
                   </div>
               </figure>
               <div class="project_inner">
                    <header class="cmsms_project_header entry-header">
                        <h6 class="cmsms_project_title entry-title">        <a href="http://test.xxxx.org.au/davetest/?id='.$animal_id.'">'.$name.'</a></h6>
                    </header>
                    <footer class="cmsms_project_footer entry-meta">
                        </a>
                    </footer>
                </div>
                <div class="cl"></div>
            </div>
        </article>';
    // Close the CURL
}
echo '<div align="center" class="ac-pages-wrapper">';
    if ($prpage > 1)
        echo '<a href="?pg='.($prpage - 1).'" class="first" title="Back"><</a>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $prtotalpage; $i++)
    {
        if ($i == $prpage)
            echo '<a href="?pg='.$i.'" class="current">'.$i.'</a>';
        else
            echo '<a href="?pg='.$i.'" class="page">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
    if ($prpage < $prtotalpage)
        echo '<a href="?pg='.($prpage + 1).'" class="last" title="Next">></a>';
echo '</div>';
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What's the code used to produce this? That's important.

Comment: all the articles have `position: absolute` and the same `top/left: 0px;`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you want help, you will need to respond to the comments at some point.

Comment: Apologies, weekend and kids!  Back in the office now.  I'll post the entire code, slightly redacted.

Comment: @BlackDog Your question is Unclear because we don't have any sample input to test with.  We don't know what your current rendered output looks like and we don't know what your desired rendered output looks like.  If you wish to receive support on this question, please edit it to include all requested information.